# Group by doesn't work correctly with order

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

My query which looks like this gives result which is shown at the bottom.
Problem is, that data are not correctly shown. Like you can see I have there order by ORDER BY `id` DESC and it still orders it by id asc. But I think it's because of GROUP BY. If I just use that sub query then it's ordered correctly but I still need to group it by candle. Please, can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT * 
    FROM eurusd_min_all_t
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    ) AS t1
GROUP BY candle 


id             time           open   high    low    close   candle
16955   2014-12-30 13:45:00 1.2158  1.2162  1.2154  1.2157  15m
31676   1998-01-05 23:00:00 1.0834  1.0985  1.0815  1.0834  1D
23951   2014-09-26 00:00:00 1.2750  1.2752  1.2748  1.2751  1H
37060   1998-01-30 23:00:00 1.0834  1.1203  1.0733  1.0783  1M
36158   1998-01-09 23:00:00 1.0834  1.0985  1.0778  1.0829  1W
27294   2012-06-15 03:00:00 1.2632  1.2636  1.2614  1.2615  4H
1       2015-01-20 18:25:00 1.1561  1.1565  1.1560  1.1564  5m
```

Comment: `GROUP`ing `BY` a `SELECT *` is usually useless anyway. In your case, it certainly is. Narrow the columns you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` works perfectly correctly, when you use it correctly.  If you abuse the language, you will not get the results that you expect.  Start by reading this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), and understanding what it means to have extra columns in the `select` of an aggregation query.  I am sorry that you expected your query to do something that the language *explicitly* is documented not to do.

If you want the most recent `id` for each candle, use the typical `join`/`group by` method for it:

```
select t.*
from eurusd_min_all_t t join
     (select candle, max(id) as maxid
      from eurusd_min_all_t
      group by candle
     ) c
     on t.candle = c.candle and t.id = c.maxid;
```